# Data structures provided by Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, windows

I am developing a program with the Win32 API. Are there any data structures that Windows provides like singly-linked list, trees etc. as part of Win32 API? If so please let me know how I can use them (at least headers which I need to include to use them).  I already heard that there is `LIST_ENTRY`.  Can I use it from user mode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The Win32 API has a [singly linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684121(VS.85).aspx) implementation. I don't think there are any other data structures in the API.

But, the singly linked list is designed for inter-thread queues rather than general algorithmic data processing. Better to use your language's own general purpose data structures which will not be so specialised (eg. C++'s STL data structures and associated algorithms are much richer that anything in the system API).